# Get the previous and next three values from an column of pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I am new to python and pandas. Here, I have a dataframe where I have two columns.

```
Offset       predictedFeature
 0              2
 5              2
 11             0
 21             22
 28             22
 32              0
 38             21
 42             21
 52             21
 55              0
 58              0
 62              1
 66              1
 70              1
 73              0
 78              1
 79              1
```

So, in this df I am trying to get the previous 3 values from the `predictedFeature` column of those where value is `0`.
  So for e.g. 3rd row value is `0`, so I am trying to get previous 3 values which are `[2000, 2000]` and next three are `[2200, 2200, 0]`. I am trying this for every `0` which is in the `predictedFeature` column. So that I can get a `df` which will have these two as new columns: Previous and next values.

```
Offset       feature       previous        Next            NewFeature 
 0              2             -             -                 2
 5              2             -             -                 2
 11             0           [2,2]          [22,22,0]          0
 21             22             -            -                 22
 28             22            -             -                 22
 32              0          [22,22,0]      [21,21,21]          0
 38             21            -              -                21 
 42             21            -              -                21
 52             21            -              -                21 
 55              0           [21,21,21]     [0,1,1]            0
 58              0           [0,21,21]      [1,1,1]            0   
 62              1             -              -                1
 66              1             -              -                1
 70              1             -              -                1
 73              0           [1,1,1]         [1,1]             1 
 78              1             -               -               1
 79              1             -               -               1
```

Comment: I'm curious what your intention is behind this non-normalized data structure. Why having lists as pandas elements? Why not 3 + 3 columns `prev3`, `prev2`, ..., `next3`? Are you sure your problem is correctly defined?

Comment: Actually, i want to replace the 0 with one of the values from its previous and next values. If previous 3 values are same as that of next three then that 0 will get replaced with the value from that array.

Comment: What is your intended bahaviour at the beginning and end of the table where you don't have 3 prev / next values?

Comment: If not then we can add na over there or 0 value or something like that mau be you can suggest

Comment: If your actual goal is to just replace the zero values, you don't need `previous` and `Next` columns in your expected output. So I assume they are just for illustration now?

Answer (score 1):

You can apply a windowed view on the array via [`numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided.html). Here is a function I created some time ago for exactly that purpose. It's a bit tricky to understand. Essentially the function just modifies the memory-steps or *strides* along the newly created axis in a way that each row shows a shifted version of the previous.

```
def windowed_view(x, window_size):
    """Create a 2d windowed view of a 1d array.

    `x` must be a 1d numpy array.

    `numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided` is used to create the view.
    The data is not copied. You should never write to a windowed view.

    Example:

    >>> x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
    >>> windowed_view(x, 3)
    array([[1, 2, 3],
            [2, 3, 4],
            [3, 4, 5],
            [4, 5, 6]])
    """
    assert window_size <= x.size, "window_size (%s) must be <= x.size (%s)" % (window_size, x.size)
    return np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(
        x,
        shape=(x.size - window_size + 1, window_size),
        strides=(x.strides[0], x.strides[0])
    )

df = pd.DataFrame({'predictedFeature': [2000,2000,0,2200,2200,0,2100,2100,2100,0,0,100,100,100,0,100,100]})
w = windowed_view(df.predictedFeature, 7)

[[2000 2000    0 2200 2200    0 2100]
 [2000    0 2200 2200    0 2100 2100]
 [   0 2200 2200    0 2100 2100 2100]
 [2200 2200    0 2100 2100 2100    0]
 [2200    0 2100 2100 2100    0    0]
 [   0 2100 2100 2100    0    0  100]
 [2100 2100 2100    0    0  100  100]
 [2100 2100    0    0  100  100  100]
 [2100    0    0  100  100  100    0]
 [   0    0  100  100  100    0  100]
 [   0  100  100  100    0  100  100]]
```

However you only want the rows where `0` is in the middle:

```
w[w[:,3]==0,:]

[[   0 2200 2200    0 2100 2100 2100]
 [2100 2100 2100    0    0  100  100]
 [2100 2100    0    0  100  100  100]]
```

The only problem is the beginning and end of the series you analyze, since the view only contains rows with the full window. You're missing some zeros there. However you could iterate over the first and last row of `w` and handle these cases seperately. Hope this helps so far.

Comment: I want to have the previous and next values only of 0 not like they should be in middle.. Wherever there is a 0 it should get this values

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Maybe you can present your expected output?

Comment: I have just updated with the expected output. It has a bit indentation issue.. Previous and next are the column names. Na is for those whose value is not 0 in predicted feature column

Comment: Here,is there any way I can get the offset value as well for which it is getting previous and next value.So that I can check weather previous and next values are same or not if same then I can replace that value

Comment: I have just updated the question with a proper expected output. Please check once.